# SQLite Versioning. Is it possible to use EXCEPT to show differences between rows where only one column changes?

Tags: sqlite

I'm quite new to SQLite and I'm trying to use an EXCEPT statement in order to compare two tables with very similar data. The data comes from a CSV file I download daily, and within the file new rows are added and deleted, and old rows can have one or more columns change each day. I'm trying to find a way to select rows that have had a column's data change, when I am unable to predict which column's data will change.

Say for example I have:

```
TABLE contracts:
|ID|Description|Name|Contract Type|
|1 |Plumbing   |Bob |Paper        |
|2 |Cooking    |Ryan|Paper        |
|3 |Driving    |Eric|Paper        |
|4 |Dancing    |Emma|Paper        |
```

and:

```
TABLE updated_contracts:
|ID|Description|Name|Contract Type|
|1 |Hiking     |Bob |Paper        |
|2 |Cooking    |Ryan|Paper        |
|3 |Driving    |Eric|Paper        |
|4 |Dancing    |Emma|Digital      |
```

I'd like it to return:

```
|1 |Hiking     |Bob |Paper        |
|4 |Dancing    |Emma|Digital      |
```

because contract 1 has changed the description and contract 4 has changed the contract type.

Is it possible to do this in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with a `LEFT` join of `updated_contracts` to `contracts` where the matching rows are filtered out:

```
select uc.*
from updated_contracts uc left join contracts c
using(id, Description, Name, `Contract Type`)
where c.id is null
```

`EXCEPT` can also be used like this:

```
select * from updated_contracts 
except
select * from contracts
```

This will work only if the tables have the same number of columns and its advantage is that it compares `null` values in columns and returns `true` if they are both `null`.

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oRK3ifN1xmZcUNgSGTQP3Z/1).

Results:

```
| ID  | Description | Name | Contract Type |
| --- | ----------- | ---- | ------------- |
| 1   | Hiking      | Bob  | Paper         |
| 4   | Dancing     | Emma | Digital       |
```